# What does "won" mean in "the shot that won"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ralph and Gary are talking about the basketball game they saw on TV last night:

> Ralph: Did you watch the game last night?
>
> Gary: I sure did. I wouldn’t have missed it for anything!
>
> Ralph: I think it was one of the best games I’ve ever seen.
>
> Gary: Me, too. I thought both teams played super ball.
>
> Ralph: Too bad one had to lose.
>
> Gary: Yeah, they were evenly matched. It could have gone either way!
>
> Ralph: The shot that **won** in the last fifteen seconds was really something.
>
> Gary: I agree with you there.

Source: The ILI English Series, Intermediate 2, Student's book, Page 81

Answer (score 1):

*Win* usually means *to achieve first position*.

> The shot that won the game...

Here the sentence is used *metaphorically* meaning that it was the shot which helped to win that game.